# How to Deploy heroku app from url path / subdirectory -- not url root?

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js

By default heroku will deploy your app from the root of the url `https://random-name-12345.herokuapp.com/`. How do I deploy a heroku app from a specific path / subdirectory like this `https://random-name-12345.herokuapp.com/homepage` ? If someone visits `https://random-name-12345.herokuapp.com/` they can get a 404 -- I do not need it to redirect.

The above app is running a node server and using nuxt SSR.

To rephrase the above, effectively I want to see this in my heroku deploy logs when a deploy completes:

```
https://random-name-12345.herokuapp.com/homepage deployed to Heroku
```

And not:

```
https://random-name-12345.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Is your app similar to this : https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template ?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yep! It is pretty similar to https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template